# Apache SSL certificate placed in correct dir but SSL cert invalid in browser

Tags: apache, google-chrome, ssl

This is more of a clarification question because I didn't know what to Google in order to find an answer.

I generated a csr for my website domains and ordered the certificate from Digicert. Followed the [instructions](https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/apache-openssl.htm) to place it in the correct directory. `apachectl configtest` prints no warnings or errors. I ran the `Django` sever and it runs fine on `8080`.

**Problem**: I purchased the certificate for my website domain, i.e., something like `www.example.com` not an IP address. At the moment my website is based on an AWS EC2 instance and I am accessing it via the IP address.

When I visit the website via the IP address, the area on the address bar where we can see the status of an SSL cert shows up in red with a strikethrough on the `https`. My understanding is that it is because the certificate is only for the domain and not the IP address? Can someone please explain how SSL certificates link to the website name? Does the browser go looking into the proper apache directory and then match it with the thing in its address bar? How does it all work?

Comment: "Can someone please explain how SSL certificates link to the website name?" The Apache configuration ties a specific website name to a specific certificate. When the browser does a request the webserver gets the name requested at the TLS level thanks to SNI and then from configuration find the appropriate certificate to send back to the client.

Comment: Okay, so in my case at the moment, when the IP address is typed into the browser, what happens in that scenario?

Comment: " when the IP address is typed into the browser, what happens" the webserver having then no idea what website you want to reach, it will return one "random" certificate from all he knows about, depending on its configuration, it can be either the "default" one (if Apache has a "default" VirtualHost section) or else just the first one appearing in its configuration. HTTPS works with the implicit idea of using (servers')  names, not IPs.